# is the number an event fires tied to the number of its event bindings in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I often end up with some event bindings firing multiple times in Jquery/Jquery Mobile, especially when using the new Jquery on() vs. Jquery live();

Example:

```
   $(document).on("pagebeforechange", function (e, data) {
      // stuff
      });
```

**I'm wondering the following:**
If I have multiple binds like the above, will they each fire once or will they fire as many times as I'm using the binding.

Example:
3 document/pagebeforechange listeners = every listener 1x
3 document/pagebeforechange listeners = every listener 3x

Thanks for some clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call to `.bind()`, `.on()`, `.delegate()` etc. will create a new, unique event handler and gets queued up.

So yes, each call to those methods will fire a new handler. Don't be sloppy with that.

For instance

```
<body>
    <div>
        <span>foo</span>
    </div>
</body>

$('span').on('click', function() {
    alert('span #1');
});

$('span').on('click', function() {
    alert('span #2');
});
```

This would alert `span #1` followed by `span #2` when we click on the span.

Comment: but a unique handler will not fire all the other handlers? So if my above binding is firing 4x it's not because of some other duplicate binding somewhere inside my script or another plugin I'm using?

Comment: @frequent: I don't quite understand the question. I'm not familiar with that `pagebeforechange`. It might be that this event indeed is firing more than once, so all of your handlers for this event would get fired. But that seems unlikely to me, maybe you're re-binding event handlers in some wrong/bad place.

Comment: ok. but alert('span #1') will not fire twice and alert('span #2') will also not fire twice, because I'm using two bindings?

Comment: @iAndy: thanks for the comment. It's a jquery mobile event, very likely to fire more than once. I was just looking for some general info on the way events fire. So with your info I can rule multiple binds, so next I need to check for badplace bindings. Thanks so far